# Doesn't add rows when called from different method

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to add rows to a datagridview called from different methods, but it's not working. Then I tried to trigger the add rows in a `Click` event and it works.

Can someone give me a hint or clue to fix this?

Form 1:

```
    private void btnTag_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var type = Type.GetType("Payroll." + dynamic_form);
        dynamic form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;
        form.GetEmployeeID(empid);
        this.Close();

    }
```

Form 2:

```
public void GetEmployeeID(Dictionary<int, List<int>> emp_id)
{
    //this is the add rows it's not working
    dgvTaggedEmployee.Rows.Add("sample", "sample");

    employee_id = emp_id;

    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, List<int>> item in employee_id)
    {
        foreach (int value in item.Value)
        {
            if (dbcon.OpenCon() == true)
            {
                string query = "SELECT * from tbl_payroll_employee_basic where payroll_employee_id="+value.ToString()+"";
                cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbcon.con);
                read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                read.Read();
                dgvTaggedEmployee.Rows.Add(read["payroll_employee_last_name"].ToString() + ", " + read["payroll_employee_first_name"].ToString() + read["payroll_employee_middle_name"].ToString(), "0");
                MessageBox.Show(value.ToString(), read["payroll_employee_last_name"].ToString() + ", " + read["payroll_employee_first_name"].ToString() + read["payroll_employee_middle_name"].ToString());
                dbcon.CloseCon();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _called from different methods, but it's not working_ Where and how exactly is it not working? How and where is `dgvTaggedEmployee` set?

Comment: @Taw it is not adding rows to datagridview, the expected output is it should add.

Comment: `dynamic form = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as Form;` creates a new instance of `Form`. It will not modify the DataGridView which is already opened in the Applicaiton.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya What will the alternate way to do this sir?

Comment: You need to know the current running instance of Form2 in Form1. If  you are Opening "Form1" from "Form2" the you can have a property in Form1 of the type Form2 and when you open Form1 from Form2 you need to set that property as "form1.Property = this" and use that in Form as "Property.GetEmployeeId(id);"

Comment: @ChetanRanpriya Thanks bro it's working now.